# "to become as an instructor" OR "to become an instructor"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, prepositions, relative-clauses

> When she was 14 years old, she even earned a black belt in karate. Also, she got a special training, exclusive for disabled people to become **as an** instructor."

Should I rewrite the same sentence like this?

> When she was 14 years old, she even earned a black belt in karate. Also, she got a special training, **which is** exclusive for disabled people to become **as an** instructor.

I'm also unsure about which one is correct

> To become **as an instructor**
>   OR
>   To become **an instructor**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is pretty terrible.

Lets look at your use of "even". I assume this is intended to reflect that getting a black belt at 14 years old was a high achievement. You should use "only" instead, e.g.

> When she was **only** 14 years old, she earned a black belt in karate.

The second sentence can be understood, but sounds clumsy. I would write it as:

> Also, she **received** special training, **designed** exclusive**ly** for **developing** disabled people into becoming instructors.

Or if you meant the last part of the second sentence to refer to her becoming an instructor (rather than referring to the outcome of the training):

> Also, she **received** special training - **designed** exclusive**ly** for disabled people - to become an instructor.

These two examples are better than what you proposed, but **even** I feel they could still be improved.

Comment: "for *developing* disabled people into becoming. . . " I'm not sure this is much of an improvement.